# How to link to another library in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, linker

I created a command line application. Then I realized it would be handy to be able to use code in other projects, so I added a new target - a cocoa library.
It seems to compile and a .a file is generated.

Now in another project I want to use this library. So first I added the first project to this new project as a reference.

In build settings I set  "Always search user paths" to YES, then keyed in the path to the above project in user header paths.

In build phases, "Link Binary with libraries" , I added the .a file.

Now in my new project code sense seems to work. But when I try to build, I get an error : ndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RIImageSplitter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What did I do wrong? :S I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't add file to compile sources of target. =S

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

Did you drag the static library to your project navigator?

Did you add in Target/Build Phases/ Target Dependencies?

Did you add the Header Search Path for the headers of the static library?

Good Luck!

Comment: I solved the problem! But I can't post my answer yet as I have to little XP. I didn't add the file to the compile sources of the new target. That is why it couldn't find it. I had done all the things you pointed out. Thanks! :D